# Inferred type synonym with a polymorphic typed Template Haskell definition contains GHC.Types.Any

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, ghc, template-haskell, higher-kinded-types

I'm writing some typed template Haskell code on GHC 8.10.4 . For example, the following definition gets a sane type :

```hs
fmapQ f xs = [|| fmap $$(f) $$(xs) ||]
```

but if I introduce a *synonym* to be used inline :

```
(>$<) = fmapQ
```

this typechecks as

```
(>$<) :: Code (a -> b)
      -> Code (GHC.Types.Any -> a) -> Code (GHC.Types.Any -> b)
```

instead of the expected `(>$<) :: Functor f => Code (a -> b) -> Code (f a) -> Code (f b)` .

Anybody has an idea of what's going on? This example is small enough to typecheck in one's head but it's a bit concerning for larger examples. Or should I just avoid polymorphic bits in typed TH?

---

(template-haskell 2.16)

```
{-# language TemplateHaskell #-}
...
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax (Q(..), TExp)

type Code a = Q (TExp a)
```

Comment: If you're using the Haskell Language Server to get the types, then this is probably a known bug ([this one](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/806) or [this one](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/2006)). You can check the actual type that GHC infers if you write a type signature with a hole: `(>$<) :: _` and then run the compiler.

Comment: @Noughtmare , I'm not using HLS, so I suspect the bug runs deeper .. Is this related to NoMonomorphismRestriction being on/off ? I still don't get how that works tbh

Comment: I'm getting the expected type without `Any` if I include the signature `(>$<) :: _ => _` and then compile with GHC 8.10.7.

Comment: That's an interesting strategy. Never thought of adding "constraint holes" before